# LibGDX creación de "mapa", Lunar Lander - Atari

Tags: android, libgdx

Estoy intentando aprender los métodos de LibGDX y he comenzado un proyecto, es el antiguo juego de Lunar Landscape de Atari.

Simplemente quiero generar el siguiente "escenario"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo quiero hacer lo que viene a ser las montañas, y claro tengo en mente las siguientes cosas para hacerlo de manera "aleatoria".

Tener la siguiente variable:

```
int NumeroPuntos
```

Esta variable va a recibir un numero aleatorio entre 30 y un máximo aún por determinar para ver por cuantos puntos geométricos se va a formar el mapa y luego unir estos puntos con un `ShapeRender`.

Pero no se me ocurre ningún modo para generar una montaña "uniforme" es decir que tenga forma de montaña y también de que tenga partes uniformes que sirvan de base (que son las que pone x2, x5, x3...)

Y la útlima duda respecto a esto es, ¿cómo hacer que se vaya generando más mapa? es decir ¿hay algún método para mover la pantalla actual por así decirlo e ir generando otra?

Por ejemplo si mi "Screen" tiene de valor `x = 100`, y de valor `y = 30`, ¿puedo dibujar fuera de la pantalla para que cuando la pantalla se mueva salga automáticamente generado?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bueno no puedo comentar debido a mi baja reputación, pero aquí te va un comentario-respuesta.

**Quieres Conectar puntos ?**

ShapeRenderer tiene la opción de dibujar líneas, solo tienes que proveer las vertices(o puntos)

```
public Constructor() {
        sp      = new ShapeRenderer();
        //Nota que cada vertice(o punto) tiene posicion x, posicion y
        puntos = new float[]
                {100,100,   //Punto1: x = 100 , y = 100
                110,200,    //Punto2: x = 110, y = 200
                115,400,    //Punto3: x = 115, y = 400
                125,420,    //etc....
                500,420};

    }
    public void render(SpriteBatch batch) {
        sp.setProjectionMatrix(batch.getProjectionMatrix());
        sp.begin(ShapeType.Line);
        sp.setColor(Color.RED);
        sp.polyline(puntos);
        sp.end();
    }
```

**Puedes crear mas puntos fuera de la pantalla?**

Si, tendrias que usar `OrthographicCamera`, usando una cámara tendrias la facilidad de poner el centro de la cámara en el jugador, asi la cámara siempre perseguirá el jugador

```
private OrthographicCamera cam;
public Constructor() {
      cam = new OrthographicCamera(viewPortWidht,viewPortHeight);

    }
    public void render(SpriteBatch batch) {
        cam.setPosition(jugador.getPosition().x,jugador.getPosition().y)
    }
```

**Recuerda borrar los puntos a medida que los mismo se vayan saliendo de la pantalla, ya que estarás dibujando las líneas de estos puntos sin ningun proposito**